# Are nil and Optional<T>.None the same thing in Swift?

Tags: null, swift

I'm a bit confused by Swift tutorials.

Is `nil` just a convenient shortcut for `Optional<T>.None`?
Is there an implicit conversion from one to another?

A couple of observations:

- `Optional<String>.None == nil`
- `nil` literal seems to have a `NilType`

If this is an implicit conversion, can I define my own type that “accepts” nil, or is `Optional` somehow special in this regard? I don't think defining custom convertible-to-nil types is a good idea—I'm just trying to understand how the type system works in this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If you don’t provide an initial value when you declare an optional
>   variable or property, its value automatically defaults to nil.

They have same value, both are `nil`.

Actually `Optional<T>.None` is a polymorphic primitive value, and `nil` is a constant having this value. `Optional<T>` is a polymorphic type. The type of `nil` is `Optional<T>`. That's why you cannot assign `nil` to anything else but an `Optional<T>`. For the same reason you cannot assign `true` to anything but a `Bool`.

For now, according to the documentation you can not use `nil` for any custom and arbitrary type but optionals.

> nil cannot be used with non-optional constants and variables. If a
>   constant or variable in your code needs to be able to cope with the
>   absence of a value under certain conditions, always declare it as an
>   optional value of the appropriate type.

Comment: But how come you can assign `nil` to `Optional` but not to anything else? Can I define `MyOptional` with the same behavior?

Comment: @Dan: I've updated the answer to cover this question. It seems it's impossible.

Comment: How/where did you find the information about Optional<T>.None?  I'm super interested.  In the Apple Documentation I'm seeing this: " In Swift, nil isn’t a pointer—it’s the absence of a value of a certain type".  Does this conflict, or are they two different ways of saying the same thing?